# clustering ejabberd on aws EC2 linux ami

Tags: amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, ejabberd, nlb

I am currently trying to cluster ejabberd using 2 EC2 instances but I am facing some problems. I have 2 instances and in front these 2 instances there is an AWS network load balancer. The network load balancer is connected to a domain name(www.example.com) and route the traffic to two instances. My current ejabberd.yml file for both instances have the following host:-

```
hosts:
  - "www.example.com"
```

For node1 I modify the ejabberdctl.cfg and change the ejabberd name like the following for example

```
ERLANG_NODE=ejabberd@1.1.1.1
INET_DIST_INTERFACE=1.1.1.1
```

where 1.1.1.1 is the private ip of my EC2 instance the same is done for second ec2 instance but with different private ip. I make sure that I have the same .erlang.cookie in same EC2 instances . The Network load balancer listens to port 5280,5269,5222 and 4369 and route traffic to 2 instances. I start my first instance by using

```
ejabberdctl start
```

and it works fine because I can access the webadmin console. I start my ejabberd on second instance using using

```
ejabberdctl start
```

and it runs fine when I try to add the cluster to instance using the following command

```
ejabberdctl --no-timeout join_cluster ejabberd@1.1.1.1
Error: {no_ping,'ejabberd@1.1.1.1'}
```

I know that instances can't see talk to each but I can't find or debug the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at those manual tips. Try them, maybe one of them gives you some clue about the problem in your setup. For example, you can see how to check both nodes use the same cookie string (just to be sure they read the correct file). You can also try to ping from one erlang node to the other manually...

https://www.ejabberd.im/interconnect-erl-nodes/index.html